# Laravel 5/ Form security (require clarification)

Tags: laravel, security

Not entirely confident I have understood security in Laravel forms enough. For example, if a form contains 
`<input type="hidden" name="user_id">`
then obviously a hacker could change the value before submitting an update.
While I have looked [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf) at CSRF, I've not fully understood if this is enough protection?

E.g. Taking the above, if I go to a site and open a form to edit a record I'm permitted to view but not change, and maliciously alter the "user_id", is it enough that the form is protected with  `{{ csrf_field() }}` or must I employ some further security such as `Crypt::encrypt($id)` to hide the user_id (held in a database) and `Crypt::decrypt($id)`?

Is it considered a bad practice to expose a row id (like a user id) in a client browser (even though everything is sent over https)?

Many Thanks

Comment: csrf doesn't really help with that particular case you're mentioning. What you want to do is to check on the backend whether the id which is being send is the same as you are expecting. 

You could also encode that user id and then decode it on backend. 
All depends on what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Here, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) read to get an idea what csrf is and what csrf token will defend you from.

Comment: If the `user_id` field is not to be changed by the user *and* not visible on the form, why sending it to the client? Put `user_id` server side on the SESSION, not client side on the form.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not enough to use just CSRF token in this case. You also need to use policies, guards, middleware to protect your app.

In this case, someone can alter the `user_id` if you read it from the form and use after that, so you need to use a policy like this one to protect data (this example is [from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#writing-policies)):

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

Also, when you need to use user ID, always use `auth()->id()` or `auth()->user()` if you need whole object. Never read user ID from the form.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I do have a middleware and in the controller I check the person editing the change has an admin role and belongs to the same company (they also wouldn't see the record if they didn't first have the same company id as the person editing - it's still not enough though).

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel framework stores the value of this CSRF field like a session variable and matches it when you submit it.

When you submit the form Laravel checks that value from the session value stored. if there is a **mismatch** an error is thrown ! 
:)

Answer (score 2):

CSRF token protect the site from cross-site requests, means an external user can't duplicate the form and send a post request. Laravel create a random session token which we place in the hidden field using csrf_field()  or Session::token() function. Laravel checks the session with hidden field value from the form before processing the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the form action. It should work.